# a place that people stop at(stopped but?) that became a ghost town

Tags: pronunciation, listening

I heard [[30:24-30:34] part of this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=1824) as follows;

> Basically the same thing can be said for the businesses in our next
> stop in Two Guns which was also a place that people **stop at(stopped
> but?)** that became a ghost town with Highway 40.

I wonder if the part in bold is '*stop at*' or '*stopped but*'.

Comment: "which was also a place that people stop but that" is what I hear

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: It's rather fast and I still listened to it twice to make sure I heard it right...

Comment: Thank you very much.